# Binding text blocks inside a user control using MVVM and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

I am still new in MVVM and WPF 
and I've looked at some examples however still did not found exactly the answers to my question.

I have a `ListBox` which each Item should add a new user control using `ObservableCollection`. In the user control I have an several Text blocks which I want to bound the texts of them to the same `ObservableCollection` which contain the Data.

However I am not sure how to bind the Text blocks to the `ObservableCollection`

Would be happy for a code example.

I'm also attaching my code, this is my userControl XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProtocolAnalyzerGui.UserControlls.MenuControlls.UCSingleLine"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="#FF454545">


    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <TextBlock x:Name="TBHeader" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TBDatanTime" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding DataAndTime }" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TBComPort" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White"  Text="{Binding ComPort }" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TBTranslation" Grid.Column="4" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Translation }" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TBDataBytesArray" Grid.Column="6" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Header }" ></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

in the main window XAML:

```
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox x:Name="LBListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <myControlls:UCSingleLine x:Name="DataUserContoll" 
 DataContext="{Binding DataForGui}"></myControlls:UCSingleLine>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

the binding of the listbox Itemsource is inside this function:

```
        private void MI_SerialPortStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LBListBox.ItemsSource = DataForGui;                
            _SerialPortTakeCare.Start();

        }
```

also attaching my dataCode:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{   

        private string _DataAndTime;

        public string DataAndTime
        {
            get { return _DataAndTime; }
            set
            {
                _DataAndTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataAndTime");
            }
        }
        private string _ComPort;

        public string ComPort
        {
            get { return _ComPort; }
            set
            {
                _ComPort = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ComPort");
            }
        }
        private string _Translation;

        public string Translation
        {
            get { return _Translation; }
            set
            {
                _Translation = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Translation");
            }
        }
        private string _Header;

        public string Header
        {
            get { return _Header; }
            set
            {
                _Header = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Header");
            }
        }
        private string _Data_ARR;

        public string Data_ARR
        {
            get { return _Data_ARR; }
            set
            {
                _Data_ARR = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Data_ARR");

            }
        }

        public Data()
        {
            _ComPort = "";
            _Data_ARR = "";
            _DataAndTime = "";
            _Header = "";
            _Translation = "";
        }





    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question, as the code is not a good [mcve]. You haven't even shown what `DataForGui` is. Also, do **not** edit the code in your post as you attempt to follow instructions given by others (in comments or in an answer). Doing so _changes_ the original question, and makes it very hard to people who come along later to understand what you were asking in the first place, negating much if not all of the value of having your question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the data context of your user control and then add the appropriate bindings.

In your main window, this line should look as follows:

```
<local:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding}" x:Name="DataUserContoll"/>
```

And in the user control, the code should look more like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TBDatanTime" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TextField1}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="TBComPort" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TextField2}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="TBTranslation" Grid.Column="4" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TextField3}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="TBDataBytesArray" Grid.Column="6" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TextField4}"/>
```

... and you should change the placeholder field names I have put in (e.g. "TextField1") to be the actual string properties of the objects inside your collection "DataForGui".

Comment: no... stil doen't work it addes the new control but not the text inside.

Comment: edit my answer to show you. and also added my data code. maby something worng with that

Comment: Your updated code doesn't contain the "DataContext" binding in the "<local:UserControl1" definition in the MainWindow XAML.  That was the first part of my answer.

Comment: sorry forget to paste it. paste it now after edit same isssue.
maby it involved namespacing?

Comment: It's still wrong, you didn't paste what I showed you.  You put DataContext="{Binding DataForGui}"  It should be DataContext="{Binding} as you are setting the datacontext for the control to be the object from the ItemsSource.

Comment: Thank you James I understood the issue didn't know that writing Data Context=:{Binding}" set the datacontext for the controll to be the object from the itemsource

Comment: @PeterDuniho  The OP didn't put the data class or the field names in his original post, therefore the answer put placeholders in - I had asked him to substitute those general purpose names with his real names.  Please try to read and understood the full history of questions and answers - including the OP's edit history - before making comments like this one (which also adds zero value to the OP).